# Searching for data that is not present

Tags: excel

I have two sets of data ranges.  One range is in Sheet 1 (8000 rows, 6 columns) which is the Master Range and the other range is in Sheet 2 (5000 rows, 6 columns).  How can I display the other 3000 rows on a new sheet (Sheet 3) that are not in Sheet 2 but are in Sheet 1?

Comment: I have a few ideas - can you post some example data? Is the data in both sheets the same type of data? I.e. does Sheet1 have the same headers as Sheet2?

Comment: Sure, here is an example I threw together.  Yes, all the column headers match.  The Master lists all the data.  Part 1 lists only some rows.  I want Part 2 to display the missing rows that are not in Part 1 but are in Master.  Say, the columns are: "Name", "Birthday Month", "Age."  The Master will list 10 rows of data filled in.  Part 1 will list only 4 of the 10 rows listed in Master.  I want Part 2 to display the missing 6 of the 10 rows that are NOT in Part 1.  I don't know how to attach this file to here though.

Answer (score 0):

I can make this a macro, but first, let me know if this would do what you're looking for.

Here's the sample data I used, in three sheets.

Sheet 1 called "Master" is the following, starting in A1:

```
Name            Birthday Month     Age
Batman          January            35
Superman        March              32
Catwoman        April              37
Joker           June               28
Harley Quinn    September          33
Rorschach       July               35
Dr. Manhattan   August             41
Aquaman         October            22
Ms. Jupiter     October            23
Penguin         July               39
```

And in Sheet2:

```
Name            Birthday Month     Age
Batman          January            35
Superman        March              32
Catwoman        April              37
Joker           June               28
Harley Quinn    September          33
Rorschach       July               35
```

So, as you can see, we need Dr. Manhattan on down to be added to the (currently blank) Sheet3.

A quick way to check to see what is NOT in sheet 2, is to add a helper column to your master sheet, and simply count the number of times each record shows in Sheet2.  On your master sheet, enter this formula into D2 and copy down, `=Countifs(Sheet2!$A:$A,A2,Sheet2!$B:$B,B2,Sheet2!$C:$C,C2)`.

This will leave you with a count of times that record shows in Sheet 2.  Where you see "0", this means you need to add those records to your Sheet3:

[image]

And there you go.

Note: Since you have a huge amount of rows, you will likely get alternating 1's and 0's.  To quickly determine which haven't been included in Sheet2, simply sort all the data by Column D ("With headers"):

[image]
(Note: I originally selected the Range A1:D11, but since I chose "has headers", Excel drops the visibly selected range one row.  Hit "OK" and all the "0" reports are at the top, these you can add to your sheet 3.

I can make this a macro, but if you would kindly let me know how this works for you first.  Thanks!

Edit: Macro included, please let me know if you need any tweaks!

```
  Sub Find_Reports()
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Integer, missingLastRow As Integer
    ' Create variables for the master worksheet, the list wsht (which has SOME of the Master records), and missing WS which we will put the missing records
    Dim masterWS As Worksheet, listWS As Worksheet, missingWS As Worksheet
    Dim listWSName As String
Dim ws as Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts= false
For each ws in Sheets
     If ws.name = "Missing" then ws.delete
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts= True

    Set masterWS = Sheets("Master List") ' Change this to whatever your Master List sheet is called
    Set listWS = Sheets("Sheet2") ' same with Master, change this to whatever the second sheet (that has SOME of the data) is called
    listWSName = listWS.Name

    Sheets.Add.Name = "Missing"
    Set missingWS = Sheets("Missing")
    missingWS.Rows(1).Value = masterWS.Rows(1).Value
    missingLastRow = 2 'Start on row 2

    lastRow = masterWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'I am assuming you have NO gaps in your column A, if you do, uncomment and use the next line instead
    'lastRow = masterWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    lastCol = masterWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

    Dim countCol As Integer
    countCol = lastCol + 1 'We will add the COUNT formula to this column
    masterWS.Cells(1, countCol).Value = "Times included in " & listWSName
    With masterWS
        .Range(.Cells(2, countCol), .Cells(lastRow, countCol)).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(" & listWSName & "!C[-3],RC[-3]," & listWSName & "!C[-2],RC[-2]," & listWSName & "!C[-1],RC[-1])"
    End With

    'Now, we would add the rows with a "0" next to it in Master WS to the new "Missing" WS
    Dim i As Integer
    With masterWS
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, countCol).Value = 0 Then 'If there is no record, add to the missing WS
                missingWS.Range(missingWS.Cells(missingLastRow, 1), missingWS.Cells(missingLastRow, lastCol)).Value = _
                    .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, lastCol)).Value
                missingLastRow = missingLastRow + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With


    End Sub
```

Comment: I have updated with VBA code. Please let me know if anything doesn't work or if you have any questions!  (If this works, would you kindly mark as the answer? Thanks!)

Comment: It added the new sheet just fine, but its giving me an "overflow" error RunTime error 6 and points to the code:
lastRow=masterWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
and I do not have any gaps in my column A

Comment: Add a single apostrophe before that code, since there's no gaps, you can use the one above.  Note: I have updated the code, so you can rerun it without running into an issue if the "Missing'' sheet already exists.

Comment: Technically you could - but this is a great opportunity to learn some VBA and what's going on.  Note I also changed the type to LONG, instead of Integer, for the last row.  Recopy all of the code and try again, let me know what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry...its giving an error at: 
For i = 2 To lastRow

Comment: @Megan - What does the error say? If you step through it (Press F8 when looking at the code in VBA), does lastRow get set properly? After that line runs, you can hover the mouse over "lastRow" and it'll tell you what value that has.  It sounds like it may not be setting that variable correctly.  The sheet names are correct, or have been edited, correct? (I.e. you do have a "Master sheet" and if not, you've changed that reference in the code to whatever the master sheet's name is).